# How to change background color of click view android using base Adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I want to set the background color of clicked `TextView` included in `LinearLayout`. But I am unable to set the respective background. I faced not
clear previous clicked background . if I clicked all then set all background color. 
Would you suggest me ,
 how to set clickable `TextView` included in `LinearLayout` background.

Here is my sample code:

```
holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_cell_text_dummy_multilevel);
    holder.l_select = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear_select);

 holder.txtName.setTag(position);

    holder.txtName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                select_pos=(Integer) holder.txtName.getTag();
                    if (position==select_pos) {
                        holder.l_select.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }else {
                        holder.l_select.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: set the tag to the textview before you get the tag

Comment: I already did. see my edited question.

Comment: use setBackground instead of setTextColor

Comment: background color is not my problem. when first i clicked position 1 then its background change, if next time , i clicked positi0n 4 then also position 4 background color. here two 1 and 4 change color. so on. I want only clickalble background change.

Comment: You want the background colour change on click only and revert to original when un-clicked?

Comment: that is because `select_pos=(Integer) holder.txtName.getTag();` this will always return true.. :)..wait il come back with an aswer

Comment: go through [this](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) may be theres something missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this much done, though you will have to do some homework and find out how to reflect the changes yourself. At the moment, the change gets reflected only when the view is scrolled.

But i hope it helps you.

1.declare a static variable that sets the position clicked on

```
private static int selectedPostion;
```

2.set the `selectedPosition`'s value to -1 in the constructor

3.in the `getView` method in the `onclickListener` do this:

```
 int value = (Integer)((TextView)v).getTag();

Log.e("tag","(TextView)v).getTag() : " + value);
Log.e("tag", "position : " + position);

if(value == position) {
selectedPostion = position;
}else {
    selectedPostion = -1;
}
```

4.Under the onClick code entirely before return view write this:

```
if(selectedPostion == position) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.even_color));
    // or  holder.l_select.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}else {
view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    // or holder.l_select.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, you idea not work, look at my full code, something, i can see my textview text. look at my whole code.http://pastebin.com/bTH7y2dd

Comment: you need to write the if condition in #3, inside the onclick listener of the textview. It will only work if you scroll so you will have to look for a  work around for the same